# javascript form validaton, Validation message Disappear Quickly

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to show the validation message next to the Input Field, 
the code works perfect when i remove the FORM tag, but using FORM the Validation message disappears quickly,(blinks)

```
                <h4>age must be 18 to 40</h4>
            <form name="regestration" >
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="age">
                </div>
                <p id="demo"></p>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="return myFunction()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>


<script>

function myFunction() {
    var x, demo;

    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("age").value;

    // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
        if (x=="") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please Fill The Box";
        }
    else if (x<18) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You Are UnderAge";
        }
    else if (x>40) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You Are OverAge";
        }
    else {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `button type="submit"` will submit the `form` and hence your page will get `reloaded` unless your `submit` handler is returning `false`

Use `button type="button"`(`form` will not be submitted, `FORM_ELEMENT.submit()` will help!) or `e.preventDefault()` to prevent behavior of the `submit` button.

(**Edit:** *`<button type='button'` will act as a  button which can not `submit` the fomr hence you will have to submit the form invoking `FORM_ELEMENT.submit()` method. If you are using `type='submit'`, then use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent behavior of submit button.*)

As you are using `return FUNCTION_NAME()`, your function must return `false` to stop form submission. and `return true` for those conditions where you want `form` to be submitted.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, demo;
  x = document.getElementById("age").value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please Fill The Box";
    return false;
  } else if (x < 18) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You Are UnderAge";
    return false;
  } else if (x > 40) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You Are OverAge";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>age must be 18 to 40</h4>
<form name="regestration">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="age">
  </div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="return myFunction()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I will not mind downvotes. But care to give valid reason!

Comment: `Use button type="button"` if he changes to this. He will never be able to submit his form.  even if its valid.

Comment: Also remove the `return false;` from the last else.. at this stage it is supposed to submit the form

Comment: @Reddy, OP would not have written that statement if he would not want to have that message!

Comment: @RayonDabre In that case I think the form itself is not required here. I agree the HTML and the thing he is trying to achieve is not in sync.

Comment: thanks everyone, know i have noticed the sideeffects of button type="button", but still thanks for cooperation, and @Rayan, i didnt understand "Use button type="button"(form will not be submitted, FORM_ELEMENT.submit() will help!) or e.preventDefault() to prevent behavior of the submit button.", coz i m not that much good in js, i m studing that,

Comment: @Rayan , your "Return true" works perfectly at the movement, and i hope there will be no sideeffects of thatt

Comment: `<button type='button'` will act as a `non-submit` button hence you will have to submit the form invoking `FORMELEMENT.submit()` method. If you are using `type='submit'`, then use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent behavior of submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the message beside the `input`? That has nothing to do with the `form` tag.

It is because the input is in `div` and the message is outside of that one. A `div` is block-level element.

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block.

So you have to place the `#demo` inside the same container as the `input`. Then you'll see the message is still underneath it. That's becuase it's wrapped in a `p` element. Which is a... block-level element.

Change `<p id="demo"></p>` to `<span id="demo"></span>` and you're done.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d1v61dkx/2/)**

**edit**
The `return false;` in my demo prevents the form from submitting for test purposes.